# Adding a class using addClass or addAttr just adds the attribute name "class"

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have written a custom "expand/collapse" functionality to expand and collapse HTML rows. To identify the expanded rows, we are adding a class - "expanded" to the expanded elements (rows without this class are identified as the ones that are collapsed.)

On page load a set of rows are added to the HTML table and our script runs to mark the necessary elements as "expanded/collapsed" and adds the necessary onClick function. This bit is working fine and we are able to expand and collapse the rows as required.

```
<tr id="abc" data-dtoggle="collapse" data-dheader="true" data-dparent="tblXyz" class="expanded">
    <td>..</td>
    ..
</tr>
```

On clicking a button in the page, a fresh set of rows are added replacing the existing rows. Our scripts run again to mark "expanded/collapsed" rows and adds the onClick functionality. But this time, though the functions are getting added as required, the class name is not getting added where required, instead just the attribute name "class" is getting added without the value "expanded."

We tried replacing the `addClass("expanded")` method with `addAttr("class", "expanded")` but with the same result.

```
<tr id="abc" data-dtoggle="collapse" data-dheader="true" data-dparent="tblXyz" class>
    <td>..</td>
    ..
</tr>
```

Do let us know if you need anymore snippets from our code.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Show `JS` code please

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` will work perfectly,please find the below code snippet attached.

> `addAttr` Please delete this syntax from your mind

Its Just `attr`.

```
 $('#abc').attr("Class",",another_class");
```

Basic difference is that `addClass` will append the classes, where as `attr` will replace the whole attribute.

> example

```
1.$('#abc').attr("Class","firstClass");
2.$('#abc').attr("Class","secondClass");
```

after executing these two lines of code `#abc` will be like this

```
After line-1.
<tr id="abc" class="firstClass">
 After line-2.
<tr id="abc" class="secondClass">
```

But in the case of addClass it differs

```
$('#abc').addClass("firstClass");
$('#abc').addClass("secondClass");
```

After executing these two lines of code `#abc` will be like this

```
After line-1.
    <tr id="abc" class="firstClass">
After line-2.
    <tr id="abc" class="firstClass secondClass">
```

Hope it helps you!!

```js
$('#abc').attr("Class",",another_class");
$('#abc').addClass('expanded');
setTimeout(function(){
alert($('#abc').attr('class'));
 },500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="abc" data-dtoggle="collapse" data-dheader="true" data-dparent="tblXyz" class="expanded">
    <td>Hello</td>

</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: addClass IS working perfectly fine on the first page load. However it doesn't add the required class once we click on the button to add a fresh set of data.

Comment: Has addAttr never been used is JS or has it just changed to attr? I am asking since I just got a job to maintain old JS where they use addAttr and IDK what it does nor can I find info about it.

Answer (score 0):

To add/remove classes, use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()`.

As in `document.getElementById('abc').classList.add('newclass')`

You can also use `classList.toggle()` if you want to more easily toggle a class on and off.

By trying to set the class manually, you run into difficulty if you have more than one class and only want to add or remove one of them.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList for info about `classList`.

Comment: I would recommend $('#abc').addClass("expanded") instead of getting the element like that. They're only adding one class.